# Full html page as startpage in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Fairly new to MVC, and on my first schoolbased internship!

Im creating a mvc project and they are asking me to set an already finished html page as
"Home page" for the project. This homepage will "if links are clicked" redirect to the mvc
project and what i am creating.

Are there any particular guidelines or ways of how to do this in an pure "MVC correct" fashion?

Getting my info from wherever it is possible, so answers would be very appreciated!

Comment: What's "an already finished html page" in this context? Have you been given a complete HTML file to implement in your project, or should you simply have a separate page (without the default layout) as the home page?

Comment: Well, it isnt only a file. Its a full folder with css and images and so on. It will eventually be put as a startpage with my mvc project "catagolized, sorry for the english if its wrong" underneath the start page. But for now i want it inside my project for trying some stuff:P

Answer (score 0):

You should first create some layout page like this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()        
</body>
</html>
```

In view associated with Home controller Index action place your already finished html code. Remove from there tags already existing in layout.

And after it modify all links url which referencing to your project actions to something like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Home","SomeAction")'>Link</a>
```

Comment: Problem is that i already have the folder with the html page, css, images and so on. I will have it inside my project for now due to some testing, but the customer is going to have the control of it so my mvc project will be place underneath their startpage in order for them to be able to modify the startpage with layout and everything in their own fashion while i will be in control of the system that is my mvc project. Sounds a bit strange but that is their request and my assignment:P

Comment: Host your folder with html,css, js files on IIS as separate web site. After it add your asp .net mvc project as another application    near with another port (for example 8080). Links from web site should refer to your web application.

Comment: Ok! Guess thats pretty much the best way to do it then. Was thinking i would be able to use some route.config stuff but well. The simpler the better. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I presume you use Visual Studio for that, right?

1. Open it, go to File > New Project
2. Select **ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application** (here you can have many versions of MVC available)

Visual Studio will create a sample application with everything created for you. **Study it**.